# Set the position of Image View

Tags: ios, swift, image

I want to change the position of image view that is based on different devices.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier0, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CelebrityHeaderCell
    let CelebrityTopObj = self.mCelebrityTop[indexPath.item]

    if CelebrityTopObj.video_pic != nil
    {
        SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: CelebrityTopObj.video_pic), options: .LowPriority, progress: { (min:Int, max:Int) -> Void in
        }) { (vimage:UIImage!, error:NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, finished:Bool, url:NSURL!) -> Void in
            if vimage != nil && finished
            {
                if getScreenHeight()<=568 {
                    cell.VideoImg.image = imageResize(vimage, sizeChange: CGSize(width: self.screenWidth/2.5, height: self.screenWidth/3))
                    cell.PrevIcon.image = imageResize(UIImage(named: "icon_prev")!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
                    cell.NextIcon.image = imageResize(UIImage(named: "icon_next")!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
                    cell.TopName.font = cell.TopName.font.fontWithSize(15)
                    cell.PrevIcon.frame.origin.x = 10
                    cell.PrevIcon.frame.origin.y = 30
                    cell.PrevIcon.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 30, width: 25, height: 25)

                } else {
                    cell.VideoImg.image = imageResize(vimage, sizeChange: CGSize(width: self.screenWidth/2, height: 100))
                    cell.PrevIcon.image = imageResize(UIImage(named: "icon_prev")!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 55, height: 55))
                    cell.NextIcon.image = imageResize(UIImage(named: "icon_next")!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 55, height: 55))

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell 
}
```

I want to set the position of `PrevIcon` by using `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` but it doesn't work. How do I do to set the position?
http://gfamily.cwgv.com.tw/public/images/iphone5.png

Answer (score 1):

To set the new position try something like that:

```
cell.PrevIcon.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: cell.PrevIcon.frame.bounds.width, height: cell.PrevIcon.frame.bounds.width)
```

To change a parameter of the "frame" you have to set it with CGRect(). You cant edit just a single value.

Comment: I have tried the method but it didn't work.http://gfamily.cwgv.com.tw/public/images/iphone5.png My code is "cell.PrevIcon.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 25, height: 25)"

Comment: It is regular, syntax correct code. It should work – if it doesn't the problem is elsewhere. Are you sure the code get executed and you are in `if getScreenHeight()<=568 { ... }`? 

The Screenshot doesn't help me to figure out your problem. But Why are you resizing your images? Just use `cell.PrevIcon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit`

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at size classes in storyboard.  Size classes enables you to have different layout constraints for different device types and orientations.  Here is a link to a quick [tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/size-classes-ios8-xcode-6).